# Closet door too short

Tags: doors, installation, closet

I'm looking to install a sliding closet door in my office. The height of my doorway is 100 inches but the only standard sliding door I was able to find was 96 inch. Theres a 1-2 inch adjustment but its still too short by 2 inches.

I'd like to get some suggestions on how I can make this work?

Thank you for your help![image][image]

Comment: Build your own custom doors? Make your opening shorter by adding structure to the top?

Comment: Is this a complete unit we are talking about. track and all? I would just install a filler strip of wood at the top, then fasten the upper track/guide to that.

Comment: Is this "your" office as in "able to make physical changes? Is the existing framing wood or metal? If it is wood (even if it is metal, but wood a bit easier) you can build down a few inches easily enough.

Comment: I added a picture. It's an old house and right now there's just an opening with a built in unit. There's no track or framing and the opening goes from floor to ceiling. There's also a molding covering the top.

Comment: It's an "old house" doesn't tell us if it's _your_ house. Do you own (thus you can make any modification you'd like) or rent (thus must get landlord approval for permanent changes, if any are allowed at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though someone is using it as a closet, that is an "alcove", so it was not built to have a door. So you will have fitment issue no matter what you do; the crown molding at the top is a problem, the baseboard on the left side it another, where a sliding door would slide to is a problem, etc. etc. etc.

Were it me, I would make a new top header extending down just below that crown molding and add some right side trim to give a straight edge for it to close against, then use a "barn door" external track system on the wall to the right. Ignore the color and style of this door, but here is an example of the type of slide system.
[image]